# VB.NET - Can't select form when paused in debugger like VB6 allowed

Tags: vb.net, debugging

When my VS2012 VB.NET application is paused in the debugger, I want to view my form but nothing happens when I click it in the taskbar. It doesn't even appear if I hide all other windows. VB6 let me view my form when in the debugger and I could see items being updated as I stepped through my code. How can I view my form when paused in the debugger?

Comment: If you have a second monitor you can drag the window to there and you'll see for example textboxes change... But just make sure you don't have anything hiding your form, it won't get fully redrawn when you are "paused" in the debugger.

Comment: Yeah - I don't see how that could work?  If you're stepping through a GUI event-handler with the debugger, nothing can be refreshed/repainted.

Comment: OK, VB.NET dropped this cool VB6 feature but did add many others so I guess I can't complain. I just have to make sure no other window obscures my form before pausing in the debugger. Curious what percentage of coders have multiple monitors just for this purpose - I have a single monitor brain!

Comment: All of them.  Well, minus one.